# Passar variável query buider Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, querybuilder

Eu estou tentando fazer esta função com Laravel Query Builder

```
public function getEstudantesCargaHoraria(Request $request)
{
    $ano_letivo = $request->ano_letivo;
    $turma_id  = $request->id;

    $ano_letivo = 2017;
    $turma_id   = 528;

    $estudantes = DB::table('turmas_has_estudantes')
        ->leftJoin('estudantes_identificacao', 'estudantes_identificacao.id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.estudantes_identificacao_id')
        ->leftJoin('estudantes_carga_horaria', function ($join) {
            $join->on('estudantes_carga_horaria.estudantes_identificacao_id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.estudantes_identificacao_id')
                ->where(function ($query)  use ($ano_letivo) {
                    $query
                    ->whereNull('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo')
                    ->orWhere('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo', '=', $ano_letivo);
                });
        })

        ->select(
            'turmas_has_estudantes.id AS turmas_has_estudantes_id',
            'turmas_has_estudantes.numero',
            'estudantes_identificacao.nome_completo',

            'estudantes_carga_horaria.id AS estudantes_carga_horaria_id', 
            'estudantes_carga_horaria.estudantes_identificacao_id',
            'estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo',
        )
        ->where('turmas_has_estudantes.turmas_id',     $turma_id)
        ->orderBy('turmas_has_estudantes.numero')
        ->orderBy('estudantes_identificacao.nome_completo')
        ->get();

    return $estudantes;
}
```

Aparece mensagem de erro: Undefined variable: ano_letivo

Eu pesquisei na Internet e recomendavam colocar: use ($ano_letivo) mas, não funcionou. Continua não reconhecendo a variável

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando uma Closure dentro de outra. Para isso, você precisa passar a variável para o escopo da segunda Closure através de `use`.

O seu código está assim:

```
->leftJoin('estudantes_carga_horaria', function ($join) {
    $join->on('estudantes_carga_horaria.estudantes_identificacao_id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.estudantes_identificacao_id')
        ->where(function ($query)  use ($ano_letivo) {
            $query
            ->whereNull('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo')
            ->orWhere('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo', '=', $ano_letivo);
        });
})
```

Deveria estar assim:

```
->leftJoin('estudantes_carga_horaria', function ($join) use($ano_letivo) { // preste atenção nessa linha

    $join->on('estudantes_carga_horaria.estudantes_identificacao_id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.estudantes_identificacao_id')
        ->where(function ($query)  use ($ano_letivo) {
            $query
            ->whereNull('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo')
            ->orWhere('estudantes_carga_horaria.ano_letivo', '=', $ano_letivo);
        });
})
```

Ou seja, toda vez que você usar uma Closure dentro de outra e quiser usar a variavel do escopo principal, é necessário "repetir" o use pra cada uma delas.

Vou dar um exemplo fictício

```
$a = "valor";

call(function () use($a) { 

    return function () use($a) { 

        return function () use ($a) {
            echo $a;
        };
    };
})
```

Comment: Que coisa estranha!! rsrs Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrgado!!